# Measuring the length of a fraction of a pixel

Tags: python, image-processing, imagej, roi

I have a disk that I want to cut it in wedges, just like a pizza, I did this with ImageJ,

[Disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdQon.png)

but as you can see in the picture, there are some pixels that has a fraction inside a ROI and the other fraction inside the other ROI.

[Fractioned Pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfmSD.png)

Is there a way to find how much fraction of the area of the pixel lies in either ROIs? Ideally, I wouldn't want to do any kind of Interpolation, and write a python code for automating that.

Eventually, I'd want to measure the raw intensity of each ROI in each time frame and generate a kymograph of the resulting array.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated, even if it doesn't answer my question directly.

Comment: Sounds like a pure math question to me.

Comment: This is a pure geometry question

Comment: I agree it is, I want to translate the geometric answer to a piece of code.